# Почему меню на адаптивной верстке скрыто?

Tags: html, css, html5, адаптивная-верстка

Всем добрый вечер! Столкнулся с проблемой, при переносе html шаблона на CMS возникла проблема с меню. Оно не открывается на мобильном разрешении. Что-то блокирует.

Буду чрезмерно благодарен, если тыкнете меня в ошибку.

Comment: У вас на сайте также наблюдаются проблемы с подключением шрифта "FontAwesome". Проверьте, существует ли файл ".woff2" в указанной директории.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `script.js`, который на новом сайте, наблюдаю следующее:

```
var touch=$('#head-menu-button');
var menu=$('#head-menu-wrap');

$(touch).on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();menu.slideToggle();
});
```

ID, наверное, поменяли, но забыли заменить ID блоков.

Answer (score 0):

Какой то из скриптов jquery не подключили

Подтверждение
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: самое удивительное, что те же самые скрипты подключены

Comment: @BenjaminButton, посмотрите на скрин.

Comment: @visman Каюсь, у меня путь неверно был указан - исправил подключив в футере. Но теперь тоже самое.